# Can't get elastic IP assigned to EC2 instance within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to assign an elastic IP to an EC2 instance so that, if I ever have to resize the EC2 instance, the IP doesn't change.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

First, I followed the "Creating a VPC" section of this tutorial (note: I'm not using Elastic Beanstalk, only EC2 and RDS):

https://deliciousbrains.com/scaling-laravel-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-2-setting-up-vpc-rds-elasticache/

I'm also going to be using RDS, so according to the article I had to create a second public subnet.

Then, I created an EC2 instance, making sure to select my VPC. For the instance's subnet, I chose the first public subnet (not sure if this is correct).

I'm not sure how to continue from here though. Is my elastic IP (that I created during the tutorial of the article I linked) assigned to my EC2 instance now? If I check the details of my EC2 instance, there is no Public DNS/IP or Elastic IP set, so I assume not. But then how do I assign an elastic IP to the instance?

I tried going to the Elastic IPs section of the EC2 dashboard, selecting the elastic IP that I created during the tutorial I linked above, and choose "Associate address". Then I selected "Instance", chose the EC2 instance I just created, but it gives me an error "resource eipalloc-0b718e33 is already associated with associate-id eipassoc-123b0231".

Do I need to create a second elastic IP and assign it to the EC2 instance?

What should I do?

Comment: Haven't looked through the tutorial you linked to, but that error message sounds like you already allocated your EIP to something else. You can either create a second EIP to use with your EC2, or disassociate the first EIP and then attach it to the EC2.

Comment: The tutorial seems to assign an EIP to the VPC, so I assume that I have to create a second EIP for the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue will probably be your VPC settings won't be allowing auto-assign elastic/public IP's.